# ¿Cómo decir "it's not rocket science" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

Hace poco leía la pregunta [How to say “It's not rocket science” before rockets existed](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/278272/37429), lo que me llevó a preguntarme:

¿Qué expresión tenemos en casellano para referirnos a la expresión inglesa *"it's not rocket science"*?

En mi dialecto castellano de España se me ocurren algunas:

- No hay que ser una lumbrera
- No hay que ser un genio

¿Cuáles más se podrían utilizar? ¿Hay alguna especialmente indicada?

Comment: La primera se suele usar más bien como: "No hay que ser un lumbreras"

Comment: La que he oído más frecuentemente (pero tiro sólo de experiencia personal) es «no es neurocirugía» o las «no hace falta...» que proponen más abajo.

Comment: Me gusta como suena "no es neurocirugía."

Comment: Yo diría: "No hay que ser un cojonudo para eso."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yo utilizaría alguna cosa como una traducción indirecta

- No puede ser imposible

Si se quiere buscar más impacto, utilizaría alguna disciplina que en cierto sentido "asuste" a la gran mayoría de la gente.

- No es física cuántica

Pero también

- No hay que ser un genio
- No hace falta ser brillante
- No hace falta ser Einstein (u otra persona de público conocimiento)

Tengo entendido que `"lumbreras"` es muy usado en España. En Argentina no se escucha nunca (así como acá usamos `"capo"` en ese sentido, son cosas regionales). Seguramente en todo Latinoamérica se entenderá mejor `"genio"` o `"brillante"`. De nuevo "eso está chupado" y `"eso está tirado"` no las he escuchado jamás. Si alguien me lo dijera preguntaría qué significan.

Finalmente, expresiones como `"es pan comido"` se relacionan, incluso por traducción directa con `"it's a piece of cake"`. Bien sabemos que la frase `"it's not rocket science"` no implica `"it's a piece of cake"`. Mientras la primera implica que algo, si bien requiere algo de esfuerzo, no es imposible; la segunda implica que cualquiera puede fácilmente lograrlo

En un acto innecesario se lo pregunté a Google

[image]

También aparecen `"No hay que ser un genio"` y `"No hay que ser muy listo para darse cuenta de..."`. La última también es de distribución amplia pero es bastante larga.

Comment: +1 por `No hay que ser un genio`, y `No es física cuántica`.

Answer (score 7):

Se podría usar

> No es nada del otro mundo

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/no-es-nada-del-otro-mundo.602477/

Comment: Y para variar: *no es cosa de otro mundo*.

Answer (score 4):

- No hay que ser un lumbreras.
- No hay que ser un genio.
- Eso está tirado.
- Eso está chupado.
- Eso es pan comido.
- Coser y cantar.

No me suena ninguna más, las tercera y la cuarta suelen ser las más habituales.

Comment: Me parecen bastante regionalistas los ejemplos. No he escuchado ninguna salvo "No hay que ser un genio" y "Eso es pan comido" (siendo que esta significa otra cosa y no "it's not rocket science". Si alguien me dijera cualquiera de las otras, salvo lumbreras, preguntaría qué está queriendo decir.

Comment: @"Matias Andina" España. Quizas en latinoamerica no se usa

Comment: El OP advierte que es de España y que conoce dos. Pide más. No me queda claro que pida más sólo de España. Además, pienso que es mejor tener una respuesta mas global ;)

Comment: "pan comido" is closer to "as easy as pie"

Answer (score 2):

Otra posibilidad podría ser

> No se trata de poner un cohete en la Luna (o en Marte)

Por ejemplo

> Es simplemente una migración de la base de datos. No es que vayamos a poner un cohete en la Luna.

A diferencia de las otras sugerencias, tipo "no hace falta ser un genio/superlisto/etc." esta expresión se refiere más a la "dificultad" material que a la capacidad intelectual de quien tiene que tratar con el problema en cuestión* y además mantiene la analogía o referencia a la *rocket science*.

---

<sup>*</sup> En el fondo la expresión es "This is not rocket Science" y no "You don't need to be Einstein" o "You don't need to be the smartest guy in the world" o incluso  "You don't need a PhD in Rocket Science". Aunque una cosa y otra van de la mano en este contexto, una cosa matizar es la dificultad de la tare y otra la capacidad intelectual de quien debe realizarla.

Answer (score 2):

Como añadido a las respuestas anteriores, una que usamos mucho en mi entorno es "aquí no hacemos relojes", dando a entender que algo no es especialmente complejo o no requiere una habilidad especial.

Por contextualizar, los que más la usamos somos compañeros de trabajo, en España, en una profesión bastante técnica en momentos de hablar de algo relativamente sencillo.
Es una expresión en cierto modo complementaria a la más frecuente "aquí el más tonto hace relojes", que tiene un significado diferente.

Comment: Podrías mejorar la respuesta clarificando que es tu "entorno". Es algo que sólo decís entre tus amigos o compañeros de trabajo? En qué país? Entiende la gente de otros entornos la expresión cuando la usáis delante de ellos? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Mejor ahora? De todas formas no es la expresión más frecuente.

Answer (score -3):

Literalmente, es "eso no es ciencia/tecnología aeroespacial", que alguna vez he oído, pero hace años.

Ahora diríamos algo como "eso no es/son nueva(s) tecnología(s)".

Comment: Gracias y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Nótese que estoy buscando una expresión equivalente, no la traducción exacta de la frase.