# How does one say, "No need to be a god to help" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, méxico

Google translate has, "No hace falta ser un dios para ayudar." and to my limited understanding that sounds okay, but I have no idea. This would be US Mexican Spanish.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me (not a Mexican, though). A little more context would help. _A priori_ I'd chose a _softer_ word like _experto_ (expert) for example. Also the verb _necesitar_ could help: no necesitas ser/no se necesita ser experto...

Comment: I've never heard this phrase before. Is this a common saying where you're from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No hace falta ser un dios para ayudar` is the literal translation of "no need to be a god to help".

You could try to use `todopoderoso` (almighty) if you want to leave God or nay other gods aout of the ecuation and just convey the same:

> No hace falta ser **todopoderoso** para ayudar
>
> No hace falta ser Superman para ayudar

I don't know the context in which you'll be using this, but I'm proposing different way of saying "you don't need amazing nearly impossible qualities in order to help"

If you are looking for similar ways to say the same, check ["¿Cómo decir “it's not rocket science” en castellano?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14967/5481)" where

- No hay que ser una lumbrera
- No hay que ser un genio
- No hace falta ser Einstein

among other expressions are suggested for "you don't need to be **supersmart**". You could use other famous people to convey that you don't need to be superrich to help, or whatever needed skill could fit better in your context.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot. I write a web story that involves Wonder Woman. She's helping a American Mexican man and does a large feat of strength. He says, "No Dios..." and she responds that you don't need to be a god to help. The man is a worker assisting with a wild fire.